# What is the use case of encrypting AWS Parameter store values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-parameter-store

For an application to be able to read parameter store values I need to give it permission to do so and if secure string values are used the application/consumer also needs access to the KMS key they were encrypted with.

But what is the point of using secure strings if I already have to explicitly allow access to the value in the first place, if I allow you to request the parameter I will of course also allow you to decrypt it. Additionally the values are actually returned decrypted to the requester if they have access to the KMS key and they are requested "with decryption" so it's not about in-flight security either.

For reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-parameter-store.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameter.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/the-right-way-to-store-secrets-using-parameter-store/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same use case for encrypting EBS volumes. It prevents Amazon employees, or anyone who stole the hardware or something, from being able to access your sensitive material.

Comment: Hm, I guess that makes sense, although I wouldn't say I'm at all worried about that compared to the threat someone hacking a web facing EC2/ECS instance, at which point EBS or Parameter store encryption wouldn't be of much help at all.

Comment: It's a requirement for certain security standards like HIPAA and PCI, which also require hardening of servers like EC2/ECS instances to avoid the other issue you mentioned. It's a tool in your security belt, along with lots of other tools that you would use to fully secure your system. It is not a complete solution by itself.